# Is there something different about the nameserver requirements for the .ORG TLD?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2, bind, tld

I am running Apache2 and Bind9 on my home web-server.  I have a couple of domains registered and directing towards my server, including bjcullinan.com.  I would like to create a website for an open-source project I am starting, located at monolithicmedia.org.  I have also reserved the domain monolithicmedia.net.  By following monolithicmedia.net, you'll notice that the domain responds with a Forbidden page, because I intentionally haven't configured it in Apache as of yet.  However, the [monolithicmedia.org](http://monolithicmedia.net) domain immediately returns "Server not found".  I am wondering if I am missing some requirement of .ORG domains, as I have configured many domains and all of them seem to work just fine.  Additionally, the 'dig' command that performs a DNS lookup works just fine up until my IP address (ex dig @209.250.30.30 monolithicmedia.org responds with 1 answer).  But, it finally fails with 0 answers when I query my ISPs DNS server.  What is it that I am missing?  Is there somewhere I have to register as an official organization in order for DNS servers to recognize me?  If so, why would my registrar allow me to buy the domain without any additional information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice that the `.org` domain only has *one* dns server registered and that it's inactive, if I had to guess, I'd say you need to put two dns server, like you did for the `.net` domain.

Comment: Interesting that it shows up as inactive. What tool did you use to figure that ou ike all of my other domains as far as I know. I will have to check with my regis something wrong with the nameservers. The other concern that I forgot to men they both point to the same place

Comment: hum, the whois on the registry web site : http://74.208.44.119/index.php?mode=whois&db=content%2FWebsite&tbl=Registrants&id=3&whois_query_field=monolithicmedia.org&Submit=Check+.ORG+Whois says inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Whois shows a status of "inactive". I would contact your registrar to get it corrected.

Comment: I double checked with the registrar and remembered we removed the second nameserver as a test. I re-added ns2.bjcullinan.com as you can see from the lookup tool that mat posted. According to the tools on my registrar's website, everything looks the same as my other domains. But still no change in the response from looking it up. I don't see any differences in the whois look-up between monolithicmedia.net and monolithicmedia.org that would indicate it being inactive.

Comment: @bjcullinan: It seems to be working now.